# How to add custom project template to intellij plugin?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, plugins, project

I am trying to have a plugin which could help to show list of project structure templates in list. Once user select and hit finish that project structure should load in IDE for work same like flutter and other plugin does.

I am trying something like to get predefined added through following in plugin.xml file

```
    <projectTemplate projectType="JAVA_MODULE" templatePath="resources/projectTemplates/sample-template.zip"
                     category="false"/>
```

Comment: Have you checked this article: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/project_wizard.html ,

Comment: @y.bedrov yes i have checked but not much detailed. can you please send me any basic sample link ?